# How to merge documents and create a cover sheet

Tags: itext

I have 200+ PDF documents. I want to merge all the these documents and add an image to all the pages. I also want to create a cover sheet for the merged PDF.

Comment: Are you manipulating an *existing* document or are you creating a PDF from scratch? Also: you'll need to put more effort in your question: what do you mean when you say "edit the first page"? Do you want to add something? Do you want to change something? I'll vote to close the question as "Not clear what is asked" unless you clarify.

Comment: In have 200+ pdf, i want to merge all the pdf and in all the pages i need to add image. after merging all the pdf, i want to create a cover sheet for merged pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [MergeWithToc2](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/merge/MergeWithToc2) example.

In this example, we use `PdfCopy` to merge documents page per page. Simplified, that code looks like this:

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, baos);
document.open();
PdfImportedPage page;
for (Map.Entry<String, PdfReader> entry : filesToMerge.entrySet()) {
    page = copy.getImportedPage(entry.getValue(), ++i);
    copy.addPage(page);
}
document.close();
```

As you want to alter the contents of every page, you also need to create a `PageStamp` object:

```
PageStamp stamp;
for ( ... ) {
     stamp = copy.createPageStamp(page);
     // do stuff with stamp.getUnderContent() or stamp.getOverContent();
     stamp.alterContents();
}
```

As you want to add an `Image`, I would use `stamp.getOverContent().addImage(img, x, y)`.

As you can see, we also add a page with a table of contents (taking 1 page) at the end. We want this page be the first page, so we rearrange the pages like this:

```
reader = new PdfReader(baos.toByteArray());
n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
reader.selectPages(String.format("%d, 1-%d", n, n-1));
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(filename));
stamper.close();
```

The example [MergeWithToc2](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/merge/MergeWithToc2) ties these different pieces nicely together into one example. There are other options. You could for instance create the cover page in a totally separate document and then afterwards merge the cover note and the merged document.